# Cronjob for a zend view?

Tags: php, zend-framework, curl, cron

this isn't the best method for doing the task, but how would you run a cronjob of a zend view.

The view is used to generate a file using an `output buffer` and then save the file on the server, it runs once a day.

Would it just be a matter of calling the url of action of the controller with curl:

```
23 50 * * curl http://pclite.com/statistics/generate
```

The application required authentication though.

Answer (score 0):

If you are the admin of the server, I will not do this way,
I will code a PHP page using curl to download and save the file, since you coding a php file,you are able to simulate the login procedure , you can write the username and password in the php file, and make sure the file is saved by where you want
then  I using LYNX  in the corn, a text browser , it will call this php file once a day, so you don't have to record any username password in the cronjob and this php do what ever you wan to grab

Answer (score 0):

Since you said, that this is not the best method for doing such a task, i won't tell it again :D
If the cronjob runs on the same server your webserver is on, you could check the client-ip and skip authentication if they are the same. Because if the "attacker" can send requests from your own server to the application you really have a serious security issue.

So, yes. If you skip authentication when the ip is the same you just need to call the url.

Answer (score 0):

As any other class `Zend_View` can be instantiated from anywhere and in particular `Zend_View` can **render to a variable**. This means that you do not need to call the whole web application if all you want to do is render something.

As stated your other option is to have an entry point to the application and call it to get the return. But if you're just saving some file to the server it could be perceived as a better approach to have the cronjob be a script that does any thing. This way you will also save some load of your web application. The last thing may not be so relevant but what if in the future you want to call this endpoint several times per day for a lot of users or something? 
So, you can create a CLI script that includes `Zend_View` and renders within itself. As always with Zend Framework the implementation choice i left entirely to you.